# Send the data collected to the server at a specific time daily

Tags: android, service, google-fit-sdk

I'm getting the data using the google fit API.How can i send this data to the server daily. This should work even if the user does not open the app.I've tried 
the job Scheduler API but it's not solving my purpose.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right. You will need to create a `windows service`and install it on the same server where your database exists and then add that `Windows service` in server's `windows scheduler` set settings for it to run once on daily basis.

Now, on every run of this `Windows service`, it suppose call your `web service` and `request it` for the data and in response your `web service` should response that data to `windows service` and then that `windows service` should modify/manipulate the data to database.

Comment: any way of doing it on client side?

Comment: create and install `windows service` on client side? provide it credentials and connection string of database server.

Comment: as everything is on 'internet' it will get hit from 'anywhere' as long as internet is available?

or if its all on a local network, then they will certainly be capable of communication with provided  server names/ips